Woocommerce Reviews Page Showing Custom Comment Types
I am creating a plugin to ask questions and answers on woocommerce products, and have used the following code to create a form to ask a question, plus a function to insert the question to the comments database with the comment type 'question'.
The problem I am encountering is that the woocommerce admin reviews page shows not just product reviews, but also these custom comments.  Is there a filter or something that I can use to make the admin reviews page exclude comments with the comment_type === 'question'?  I would not want the comments with the type 'question' to show on the admin review page, because I intend to make a custom admin page for this type of comment only.

function ask_question() {
         ?>
            <form method="post">
                <?php wp_nonce_field( name:'ask-question_wpnonce' ); ?>
                <input
                    type=   "textarea"
                    name=   "question_form"
                    id=     "question_form"
                >
                <label 
                    for=    "question_form"
                >
                    <?php _e('Ask a question')?>
                </label>
                <button type="submit" class="button" name="ask_question">Submit</button>
            </form>
        <?php
    }
    function save_question() {
        if ( isset($_POST['ask_question']) && isset($_POST['question_form']) ) {
            global $post;
            $question = $_POST['question_form'];
            
            $commentdata = [
                'comment_author'        => '',
                'comment_author_email'  => '',
                'comment_author_url'    => '',
                'comment_content'       => $question,
                'comment_date'          => '',
                'comment_type'          => 'question',
                'comment_parent'        => 0,
                'comment_post_ID'       => $post->ID,
                'user_id'               => '',
            ];
            wp_new_comment( $commentdata );
        }
    }


When you say "Woocommerce reviews page", are you referring to the comment administration page? or reviews section on product page?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Fair question!  Yes, I am referring to the woocommerce review administration page showing these custom comments.  I would not want the custom comments to show on the admin review page, because I intend to make a custom admin page for these questions.

file woocommerce/src/internal/admin/productreviews/reviewslisttable.php contains a method called 'get_filter_type_arguments'
protected function get_filter_type_arguments() : array {

        $args      = [];
        $item_type = isset( $_REQUEST['review_type'] ) ? sanitize_text_field( wp_unslash( $_REQUEST['review_type'] ) ) : 'all';

        if ( 'all' === $item_type ) {
            return $args;
        }

        $args['type'] = $item_type;

        return $args;
    }

Adding &review_type=review to the URL filters out the custom comment types.
Unfortunately, Woocommerce did not provide a filter hook here, so it's not very straightforward to make the default behavior for the admin reviews page show just the comments with type review by default.
Hopefully someone could improve on this answer!
